# UIImageView does not accept images and gives Null?how to solve it.?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-4

UIImageView does not get the image and gives null, I have also tried with lazy code but still it gives null.

```
UIImageView *image_view=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, 50, 58)];

  NSString *StrImg=[[NSString alloc]init];

  StrImg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[Array_FinalobjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"coverphoto"]];

  NSLog(@"StrImg value=%@",StrImg);

 [image_view setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:StrImg] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] success:^(UIImage *image) {}failure:^(NSError *error){}];
```

Comment: plz answer dis question...

Comment: :post the result of  NSLog(@"StrImg value=%@",StrImg);

Comment: http://www.mobiappsolutions.com/nitin/FashionApp/admin/json/images1/515928a26a73c.png

Comment: the result in the url you have given above, itself contains errors.

Comment: generally this means that the image isn't where you think it is or that it's not included in the copy phase of the build.  Can you verify that the image is even in your bundle?

Comment: Array_Final has number of images with "Cover"keyword ,at index0 it gives above data (in which image have some error...i think)but other index it gives data which show image bt still image_view doesnot show any image

Comment: Log error in the failure block

Comment: can you please paste your Array_Final

Comment: i am also gtting correct image but imageview doesnot shows it

Comment: http://www.mobiappsolutions.com/nitin/FashionApp/admin/json/images1/515ab0f856ad7.png

Comment: If you enter http://www.mobiappsolutions.com/nitin/FashionApp/admin/json/images url there are list of the image names are present .But I cannot find single image there .

Comment: array final is............ coverphoto = "http://www.mobiappsolutions.com/nitin/FashionApp/admin/json/images1/515aafb8b1f4a.png";
      
    },
        {
        coverphoto = "http://www.mobiappsolutions.com/nitin/FashionApp/admin/json/images1/515aafdd46e50.png";
  
    },
        {
        coverphoto = "http://www.mobiappsolutions.com/nitin/FashionApp/admin/json/images1/515ab0f856ad7.png";
        
    },
        {
       
        coverphoto = "http://www.mobiappsolutions.com/nitin/FashionApp/admin/json/images1/515ab51102faa.png";
   
    }

Comment: @V-Xtreme: bt if u click on http://www.mobiappsolutions.com/nitin/FashionApp/admin/json/images1/515ab0f856ad7.png  u get only one image

Comment: guys problm sort.....problm was from php developr side....n i was trying since morning....Thanxss to all...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = @"http://www.hdwallpaperspk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/windows-7-wallpaper.jpg";

UIImageView *imv=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, 50, 58)];

[self.view addSubview:imv];
imv.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]]]; 




Try this code. and Please make sure that your sting is valid. means load it in web browser. it must load image in browser.
```

Comment: if i am passing value statically then it'll give image but if use parsing it won't gives image

Comment: which string you are getting after parsing? I think the string which you are using to load the image is not correct. Means there is no any image on that url string. to check this, please load that string in browser. if it has image then it should load image in browser. if you get image in browser then only you are able to load the image in imageview.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use AsyncImageView a beautiful implementation by Nicklockwood -father of iCarousel.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

it is very simple to use.

```
    #import "AsyncImageView.h"
```

and in all imageViews do this.

```
    [imageView setImage:@"default.png"];
    [imageView setImageURL:@"whateverurl/whateverimage.png"];
```

It works like a charm, and my code is in production.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your URL. Both the image name and path to the image.

eg try this link and check whether  image is coming or not.

```
http://thebooksmugglers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Kat-Zhang.jpeg
```

I hope this will work